# Dynamically resize(width) jquery dialog box based on title length?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to change the width of jquery dialog box based on the title length and have
added the all necessary js and css files include resizable js and css.

i tried to increase width but still it isn't working

Please help to solve this problem.

div for dialog box :

```
<div id="dialog" title=""
    style="display: none; font-size: 15px; width: 600; height: 400"></div>
<div align="center">
```

javascript :

```
function showMsg(title,content)
  {

      if($(title).width()>600)
          {
          $("#dialog").dialog({ width: $(title).width()+20 });
           }
      else
          {
         $("#dialog").dialog({ width: 600 });
          }

      $("#dialog").dialog({ height: 400 });
      $("#dialog").css('display', '');
      $( "#dialog" ).css('line-height','25px');
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "title",title );
      $("#dialog").html(content);
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" } });
      $("#dialog").dialog();


  }
```

html content :

```
<a href="javascript:showMsg('dynamictitle','dynamicontent');">
```

style css :

```
ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/; font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/; background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/; color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/; }
.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorHeader}*/;  background: #cccccc/*{bgColorHeader}*/ url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlHeader}*/ 50%/*{bgHeaderXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgHeaderYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHeaderRepeat}*/;   color: brown/*{fcHeader}*/;    font-size: medium; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #222222 /*{fcHeader}*/; }
```

Comment: What is that Title u r passing to the function showMsg. Is it a string?

Comment: try adding px at the end of your widths

Comment: I am passing string as title but its length exceeds

Comment: added px   width: $(title).width()+20+'px' this is not working

Comment: Donald i did what u said if it is wrong please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't calculate string width directly by calling : $(title).width().

Use this function to calculate title string width:

```
    function textWidth(text){
     var calc = '<span style="display:none">' + text + '</span>';
     $('body').append(calc);
     var width = $('body').find('span:last').width();
     $('body').find('span:last').remove();
     return width;
    };
```

Use this function like : width = textWidth(title);

Comment: Harish i dont understand here where I have to pass title value to calculate its width  and what is the different between width calculated between ur logic and $(title).width().

Comment: Title is a string, it doesn't have width property.

Comment: ok if find width then only i can change the dialog box width please help me to solve this. what u mean by this

Comment: the code u have given will give width if the element is available but here just now we are going to create so how to find the width of that title ?

Comment: string width exceeds 600px in dialog box  but that string width returned by your function is 367

Comment: You should specify style attributes like font-size(same as style attributes of dialogue title ) etc in the span assigned to variable calc inside the textWidth function.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically resize(width) jquery dialog box based on title length, go through this url - may be it find helpful to you to get proper solution: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog

Comment: there is nothing related to setting the whole dialog box width based on title length

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in term of resizing the jQuery dialog box after the initialization for any event:
Assumption - if you have the id for the element to initialize the dialog({...});

as an example,

```
$("#dialog_element_id").dialog(
{
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 400,
  width: 360,
  modal: true,
  buttons:
  {
   . . .
  }   
});

$(...).live("click, function()  
{
  var dialogElementParent = $("#dialog_element_id").parent();
  //do some logic
  //...

  //resize
  dialogElementParent.width("...");
  dialogElementParent.height("...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modification to Harish Anchu's answer lets you pass a jQuery selector and will return the width of the text with the same font styling as the selector.

```
function textWidth(text, clone_element){
    var calc = '<span>' + text + '</span>';
    var span = $('body').append(calc).find('span:last');
    var clone = $(clone_element);
    if(clone.length > 0){
        var styles = window.getDefaultComputedStyle(clone[0]);
        for(var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++){
            if(styles[i].indexOf("font") >= 0){
                span.css(styles[i],clone.css(styles[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    span.css('display','none');
    var width = span.width();
    span.remove();
    return width;
};
```